# Persistent mule object store, where are the file?

Tags: java, mule

I want to store results from the mule flows in a mule object store. It works good, but where can I find the files that is persisted?

I am using ObjectStore configuration in anypoint studio: [image]

Answer (score 1):

It all depend's on the location you provide...
For example for the following example, it stores the file in the application in a folder named **idempotent** as we have given the path here :- `<simple-text-file-store directory="./idempotent"  />`  :-

```
   <flow name="tttFlow1" >
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/aaa" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <idempotent-message-filter idExpression="#[message:payload]" doc:name="Idempotent Message"  throwOnUnaccepted="true"  onUnaccepted="ValidationFailFlow">
            <simple-text-file-store directory="./idempotent"  /> <!-- In Text file files -->
        </idempotent-message-filter>

        <logger message="Passed" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="Passed" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

      <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="EXCEPTION!" doc:name="Set Payload" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
```

Screenshots:-
[image]

reference :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-object-stores

Comment: Hmm, ok. I am using Anypoint Studio and have not seen any place to enter the directory. Maybe I need to directly use the XML for this? Added a screenshot of the Anypoint Studio config.

Comment: @JarleHansen Sadly, the `objectstore:config` doesn't allow you to set it's directory. At least not directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the object store in the below location:

```
C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202005112043\mule\.mule\mydemo-app\objectstore
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of the object store **if persistent** is the object store will locally persist at <MULE_HOME>/.mule/<>/objectstore/.

Please go through the following link for more details on Mule object store;
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/The-Different-Types-of-Object-Stores-Explained

Comment: I am trying to find persistent object store location in MacOS. Any idea, where I can find it?